# Why my code throws String was not recognized as a valid DateTime error?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

Why my code is throwing this error

> *String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

Code:

```
public static DateTime ToDate(this object obj)
{
    return Convert.ToDateTime(obj);
}
```

`obj` is `22/12/2014`

Comment: It's very probably because in the Culture that your code is running in, dd/mm/yyyy is not a valid format.

Comment: Consider yourself lucky. If you had programmed it two weeks ago, it would have sort of worked.

Comment: why ? 2 weeks ago ? didn't get you though

Comment: @VasilliSoviet: because 2 weeks ago, the day of the month was 8 and not 22, and 8/12/2014 would have parsed successfully (though not as the value you actually wanted).

Comment: In Soviet Russia, the DateTimes parse you! (sorry, couldn't resist!)

Answer (score 3):

That's because you have the Date in Different format then your system date

you should use `ParseExact` to convert datetime

```
public static DateTime ToDate(this object obj)
    {
        string dateString = Convert.ToString(obj);
        string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        return DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format,
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

If your `obj` Date id different format you need to change `format`

Comment: Of course, this assumes that the OP always wants to parse a string in that specific format. It seems likely, but it's not certain.

Comment: Best would be passing a culture indeed, that has this format.

Comment: but why it works on another server like live server ? same code, no change and that system has dateformat like dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: it may be located in different location/different time zone  ...
so they have a different time zone ..
E.g U.S. have `MM/dd/yyyy ` and uk have  `MM/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 2):

[`Convert.ToDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.convert.todatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by default.

That means, your `CurrentCulture` doesn't have `dd/MM/yyyy` (with your `CurrentCulture`'s [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) of course not `/`) as a standard date and time format.

Instead of that, you can use custom date and time parsing with [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with specific culture (eg: [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) like;

```
string s = "22/12/2014";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

Remember, [`"/"` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning as *replace me with current culture or supplied culture date separator*.

Based on your method, would be better to return `DateTime?` to return `null` outside of if statement like;

```
public static DateTime? ToDate(this object obj)
{
   DateTime dt;
   if (DateTime.TryParseExact(obj.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy",
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                              DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
   {
        return dt;
   }

   return null;
}
```

Comment: sir my client is using it in DUBAI and it works well but same code doesn''t work with me n Pakistan ? why ?

Comment: @VasilliSoviet: "works here, but not there" is almost _always_ a culture issue. You need to standardize your parsing instead of relying on current culture, if you need to handle a fixed date string format.

Comment: see if i use your code then would it work anywhere whithout any changes or error ?

Comment: @VasilliSoviet Yes, if you use this code and if your `obj` is always `dd/MM/yyyy` format, this code works everywhere because it uses `InvariantCulture` that means _culture independent_.

Comment: @SonerGönül but why it works on another server like live server ? same code, no change and that system has dateformat like dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: @VasilliSoviet I assume they (both server) don't have the same `Culture` options. You can check them in regional settings.

Comment: how to put this date format in computer ?  mm/dd/yyyy

i checked but doesn't exist

Comment: @VasilliSoviet You can't put _anywhere_ a format in your computer. Your computer has a _culture_ on your region and language part in `Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region` part. And this culture has a standard date and time formats which you can successfully parse your string without provide _any_ custom formatting in your code. Your `22/12/2014` string is `dd/MM/yyyy` format(your current date separator, not `/` of course). `mm` specifier for minutes. You want to get your code wanna support `MM/dd/yyyy` as well? `InvariantCulture` support this format. Have you ever try to use it?